# Search within a fixed width text file

Tags: php, file, search, text

Consider a fixed with file of

```
ID   TYPE      YEAR
1    Book      2000
2    Car       2007
3    Home      2005
```

Is there a way to search within a column? In fact, we need to search within characters x to y of each line by skipping the others. For instance, 5 - 15 for searching for TYPE. I prefer to find a solution in php, but if only possible in a specified language, that would be OK.

Comment: Are you saying without turning it into another data structure (like an array)? Or will loading into an array and then searching work? It looks like a space-delimited CSV to me, so you should be able to load it and go line-by-line using a substring, as well..

Comment: turning it into array will consume lots of memory.

Comment: Right, it would; it just depends on what you're wanting to do. If you literally don't care about any line without a match (filtering), just go line by line using a [CSV function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and capture the data on `strpos()`. If you're sorting (which it doesn't sound like you are), then you would probably still go line by line. I wrote that comment as I was walking out the door, so it was just the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 1):

Read each line in turn and search within it with [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) by passing in the `$offset` parameter to start the search from your column. Then check the return value and ignore a "successful" search if it actually found the result in another column (knowing the width of the target column reduces this to an integer comparison).

Alternatively, you might [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) the target column from each line and search only within that, in which case you do perform a possibly needless string operation but on the other hand you cut down on the length of the string to be searched (and there's no need to check if the result was found in another column).

In your shoes, I 'd benchmark it a bit before deciding which approach to take.